# How to populate mysql database table with metadata of uploaded file

Tags: java, mysql, file-upload, metadata, apache-tika

I created servlet for uploading files to MySQL database:

```
@WebServlet("/UploadFileController") @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)

public class UploadFileController extends HttpServlet  {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            InputStream inputStream = null;

            Random rand = new Random();
            int  n = rand.nextInt(9999) + 1;
            String idTemp=(String.valueOf(n));


            String title=(request.getParameter("title"));
            Part filePart = request.getPart("file_uploaded");

            if (filePart != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(filePart.getName());
                System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
                System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

                inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
            }

            try 
            {
                Db_Connection dbconn=new Db_Connection();
                Connection conn= dbconn.Connection();

                String sql = "INSERT INTO books (id, title, author, keywords, publication_year, filename, MIME, file) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                statement.setString(1, idTemp);
                statement.setString(2, title);
                statement.setString(3, "Goran");
                statement.setString(4, "Analisis");
                statement.setString(5, "1995");
                statement.setString(6, "OrgFileName");
                statement.setString(7, "pdf");

                if (inputStream != null) 
                {
                    statement.setBinaryStream(8, inputStream, (int) filePart.getSize());
                }

                int row = statement.executeUpdate();
                if (row > 0) 
                {
                    out.println("File uploaded!!!");

                    conn.close();

                    RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("upload_form.jsp");
                    rs.include(request, response);
                }
                else
                {
                    out.println("Couldn't upload your file!!!");

                    conn.close();

                    RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("upload_form.jsp");
                    rs.include(request, response);
                }    

            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}     
}
```

}

Right now, I input manually some strings in database instead of real metadata of uploaded file.
I'm trying to take metadata by TIKA.

```
public class MetadataViewer {

   public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException {

      //Assume that boy.jpg is in your current directory
      File file = new File("C:/Users/goran/Desktop/zadatak_grupa_B.pdf");

      //Parser method parameters
      Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
      BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
      Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
      FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
      ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

      try {
        parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, context);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      System.out.println(handler.toString());

      //getting the list of all meta data elements 
      String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

      for(String name : metadataNames) {                
         System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
      }
   }
}
```

Obvious, currently this class, right now, work only with spcified file as here, for example: `File file = new File("C:/Users/goran/Desktop/zadatak_grupa_B.pdf");` and write meta data in Console.

**How to read metadata of uploaded file and input them into database?**

Comment: What's wrong with using the `InputStream` of the uploaded file?

Comment: @Gagravarr What do you mean?

Comment: Apache Tika needs an `InputStream`. You already have code that fetches the `InputStream` of the uploaded file. Why can't you just glue the two together?

Comment: @Gagravarr I just don't know how to set any element root before upload and to write just certain metadata?
Can you help by changing my code or something? :) I hope it's not big deal if I almost have already done.